# Translation key missing outside or production

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm getting seemingly random `Translation key missing` in my environments outside of production. Production works fully, and our code base for the translations is a 1 to 1 match.

I know we're already declaring what is needed in our `server.ts`

```
  server.get(
    '*.*',
    express.static(distFolder, {
      maxAge: '1y',
    })
  );
```

and are doing lazy loading throughout the application (note: all of our overrides are working fine).

example:

```
provideConfig(<I18nConfig>{
    i18n: {
      resources: savedCartTranslations,
      chunks: savedCartTranslationChunksConfig,
    },
  })
```

This seems to be only happening with OOTB translation objects. (shippingAddress, skipLink, etc.).

This is with Spartacus 5.2.x for reference.

I looked around for other issues related, which is why I am sharing the above information, as these were usually the "STEPS" to take.

I will also mention I am already importing the `I18nModule`.